# use calculations on python csv list

Tags: python, scrapy

hey i have a list stored in csv (scrapy crawl list)

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
def handle_response(response): # the endpoint we are insterested in
    if ("/search?" in response.url):
        items = response.json()["payload"]["results"]
        data = ([(item["title"], item["display_price"]) for item in items])
        store_data(data)
```

so the item["display_price"] is a numberic value and its also very small amount = 0.0007
can u help me multiple this number by 1000 times or even do more calcutions on it ? i tried lots of stuff like *1000 but guess my very basic python knowledge is not enough !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it looks like you are dealing with a web based thing, so I suspect that the price is actually still a string.  If so, you should be able to do something like this to turn it into a floating point number, then multiply it by 1000.

```
result = float(item["display_price"]) * 1000
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html describes more about types in Python.  If you ever wonder what type a variable is, you can do this:

```
type(the_variable)
```

That returns a string describing the type, so you can print it, etc.

Comment: yes float did the job, thank you for helping me and also for the docs link, i would probably gono search for that afterward, wish u lots of luck